# mod_rewrite - how to simplify this rule?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

I am quite lame about apache and mod_rewrite, so decided to ask for help.

What I want to achieve?

```
https://myextrawebsite.com/test.php?page=default&param1=one&param2=20&param3=100&param4=........
```

to be rewritten to something like:

```
 https://myextrawebsite.com/test/default/one/20/100/
```

where paramX may be up to 40 <param1; param40>
First $_GET parameter (page) is required and all others are optional [a-z0-9]. It doesn't matter an order as I will of course parse them in PHP and verify if they are reasonable.

That's the rule I created and it works but ... it's ugly.

```
RewriteRule ^test/([a-z]+)/?([a-z0-9]*)/?([a-z0-9]*)/?([a-z0-9]*)/?$ test.php?page=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4
```

Is there any chance to do that more generic? At least first part (regex)? If there is need to have up to 40 params in url then it will be nightmare in mod_rewrite to write regex for all of them...

Comment: That's better done directly in PHP to begin with then. Rewrite `test/default/...` to `test.php?page=default&parameters=...`, and then explode that single string value at `/` in your script. If you don't want to access your parameters using array indexes, then you can also loop over the array, and use "variable variables" syntax to create individual `$paramX` variables while doing so.

Comment: yes, I know that but the thing is not about parsing it in PHP (it is quite easy) but to rewrite this mod_rewrite rule to be more pretty, now it is extremely long and ugly

Comment: Once you do the parsing part in PHP, your rewrite rule doesn't need to do much any more. `^test/default/(.*) test.php?page=$1&parameters=$2`

Comment: Just a small suggestion, every complicated code is nightmare ! Just keep using to it !